# JavaScript code golf: Shortest way to check if a variable contained a number

Tags: javascript

Unfortunately in this case 0 is false, so I can’t simply say if (x)

I’m hoping for something shorter than this to improve my code golf answer that’s shorter than these options

```
// check explicitly for 0
x||x==0

// isNaN
!isNaN(x)
```

I could remove the ! in isNaN by inverting the if else logic but the former is shorter anyway. Anything better?

UPDATE: It can be assumed that x is either undefined or a number. It by definition won’t be other truthy values such as the empty string.

To give a little more context I’m saving numbers (which will for certain be numbers do to problem restrictions) to an object than later checking that object at specified indices to see if it contains a number or undefined at the specified index.

Comment: How is the first really an option, for example when `x` is a non-empty string or an object? Also the second test will give true when `x` is a string data type that has a representation of a number, or even an array with one string value that represents a number (like `["12"]`)? Is that intended? This needs clarification in your question...

Comment: In this case I can assume that x will be either undefined or a number. 

It’s a code golf problem where I can make assumptions about the input, otherwise I agree the shortcomings wouldn’t work. I’ll update the problem with that detail

Comment: What values may you encounter and which do you want to accept? Especially with code golf, you often need to take incorrect shortcuts which happen to work in your specific situation, but would fail in others.

Comment: I’ll only encounter numbers and undefined. 

I’m basically saving numbers I encounter to an object then checking for existence of those numbers later. I’m using the object like a set data type. 

All the input will be numbers by definition so my object will contain only numbers and undefined

Comment: Are the numbers keys or values?

Comment: From your edit, could you not use `object_var.hasOwnProperty('x')` ?

Comment: @deceze the keys are numbers. The values are numbers or undefined. Strictly in both cases

Comment: @MichaelBeeson hasOwnProperty is many characters longer than ```x||x===0```

Comment: @CADBOT fair enough, but `hasOwnProperty` is useful in general to check if an object has a value assigned to a specific key, without having to run special checks for falsiness. But if you're looking for least characters (even if it means running two checks) then that's your prerogative.

Comment: Don't think code golf is a "practical" programming question to be on topic for this site, but there's [codegolf.se].

Comment: @MichaelBeeson Code golf is for sure contrived and a bit silly. It's fun though!

Comment: Is there a specific range on the saved numbers?

Comment: @CADBOT, Ha! My apologies. Never heard of it. Looks like fun!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it's nullish (`null` or `undefined`) using the [?? operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

For example these two are equivalent:

```js
if (x != null) {
  /* statement */
}
```

```js
x ?? /* statement */
```

In your specific case, you can also use it when assigning a value (`x`) onto your object (`o`) if the property (`z`) is not nullish.

```js
o.z ??= x;
```

Comment: I thought of something like this in my answer, but this might be better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Got it! I can loosy compare against null on an object I have elsewhere.

i.e.

```
/// some object o I happened to have declared
/// Some random property I don't have on it such as z
x!=o.z
/// compiles to the following
x!=null
/// which will be false for numbers and true for undefined
```